# Adding an emscripten option to a cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, emscripten

I've been working on a game engine as a hobby project, and I've successfully made it compatible with Windows using MinGW64. I'm now interested in porting it to the web via WebAssembly, leveraging Emscripten for the task.

However, I'm relatively new to using CMake and am encountering significant difficulties in modifying my CMakeLists file to support Emscripten. I'm looking for guidance or examples on how to adapt my existing CMake setup for this purpose.

Any advice or resources on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Here is the current CMakeLists.txt that I made, it compiles and build but the resulting html/wasm is all black with no console log at all whereas the windows build works totally fine

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(PgEngine VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

enable_testing()

set(TF_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF)
set(TF_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
set(TF_BUILD_BENCHMARKS OFF)

set(SDL2MIXER_OPUS OFF)
set(SDL2MIXER_FLAC_LIBFLAC OFF)
set(SDL2MIXER_MOD_MODPLUG OFF)
set(SDL2MIXER_MIDI_FLUIDSYNTH OFF)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(SDL2_DISABLE_INSTALL ON)
set(SDL_TEST OFF)

add_compile_options(-DGLEW_STATIC)

set(SDL2_DIR "import/SDL2-2.28.5")
set(SDL2MIXER_DIR "import/SDL2_mixer-2.6.3")
set(SDL2TTF_DIR "import/SDL2_ttf-2.20.2")
set(GLM_DIR "import/glm")
set(TASKFLOW_DIR "import/taskflow-3.6.0")
set(GTEST "import/googletest-1.14.0")
set(GLEW_DIR "import/glew-cmake")

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Emscripten")
    set(USE_FLAGS "-s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_FREETYPE=1")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${USE_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX .html)
else()
    add_subdirectory(${SDL2_DIR})
    #find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
endif()

if(NOT ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Emscripten")
    add_subdirectory(${GLEW_DIR})
endif()

add_subdirectory(${SDL2MIXER_DIR})

# Todo make this work
# add_subdirectory(${SDL2TTF_DIR})

add_subdirectory(${GLM_DIR})
add_subdirectory(${TASKFLOW_DIR})
add_subdirectory(${GTEST})

include_directories(${GLM_DIR}/glm)
include_directories(${TASKFLOW_DIR}/taskflow)

if(NOT ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Emscripten")
    include_directories(${SDL2_DIR}/include)
    include_directories(${GLEW_DIR}/include)
endif()


if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Emscripten")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-Wall -Wextra -g -pthread -ggdb -DDEBUG -DGLEW_STATIC USE_PTHREADS -m32 ${USE_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-Wall -Wextra -g -pthread -ggdb -DDEBUG -DGLEW_STATIC USE_PTHREADS -m32 ${USE_FLAGS}")
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-Wall -Wextra -g -pthread -Wa,-mbig-obj -ggdb -DDEBUG")
endif()

# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g -pthread -Wa,-mbig-obj -s -O3 -DNDEBUG -mwindows")

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Emscripten")
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-Wall -Wextra -pthread -Wa,-mbig-obj -s -O3 -DNDEBUG -mwindows")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-Wall -Wextra -pthread -O3 -DNDEBUG -DGLEW_STATIC -s USE_PTHREADS -m32 -sGL_ENABLE_GET_PROC_ADDRESS ${USE_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-Wall -Wextra -pthread -O3 -DNDEBUG -DGLEW_STATIC -s USE_PTHREADS -m32 -sGL_ENABLE_GET_PROC_ADDRESS ${USE_FLAGS}")
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-Wall -Wextra -pthread -Wa,-mbig-obj -s -O3 -DNDEBUG")
endif()

add_executable(PgEngine src/main.cpp)

add_executable(TetrisClone src/Tetris/tetris.cpp)

target_sources(PgEngine PRIVATE
        src/application.cpp
        src/application.h

        src/Engine/configuration.h
        src/Engine/configuration.cpp
        src/Engine/constant.h
        src/Engine/gl_debug.hpp
        src/Engine/logger.h
        src/Engine/logger.cpp
        src/Engine/serialization.cpp
        src/Engine/serialization.h
        src/Engine/window.cpp
        src/Engine/window.h

        src/Engine/2D/simple2dobject.cpp
        src/Engine/2D/simple2dobject.h
        src/Engine/2D/texture.cpp
        src/Engine/2D/texture.h

        src/Engine/Audio/audiomodule.h
        src/Engine/Audio/audiosystem.cpp
        src/Engine/Audio/audiosystem.h

        src/Engine/ECS/callable.h
        src/Engine/ECS/commanddispatcher.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/commanddispatcher.h
        src/Engine/ECS/componentregistry.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/componentregistry.h
        src/Engine/ECS/ecsmodule.h
        src/Engine/ECS/entity.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/entity.h
        src/Engine/ECS/entitycreationsystem.h
        src/Engine/ECS/entitysystem.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/entitysystem.h
        src/Engine/ECS/eventlistener.h
        src/Engine/ECS/group.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/group.h
        src/Engine/ECS/identifiers.h
        src/Engine/ECS/loggersystem.h
        src/Engine/ECS/sparseset.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/sparseset.h
        src/Engine/ECS/system.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/system.h
        src/Engine/ECS/uniqueid.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/uniqueid.h

        src/Engine/Event/eventloop.cpp
        src/Engine/Event/eventloop.h

        src/Engine/Files/filemanager.cpp
        src/Engine/Files/filemanager.h
        src/Engine/Files/fileparser.cpp
        src/Engine/Files/fileparser.h

        src/Engine/Helpers/date.h
        src/Engine/Helpers/detector.h
        src/Engine/Helpers/openglobject.cpp
        src/Engine/Helpers/openglobject.h

        src/Engine/Input/input.cpp
        src/Engine/Input/input.h
        src/Engine/Input/inputcomponent.cpp
        src/Engine/Input/inputcomponent.h
        src/Engine/Input/inputmodule.h

        src/Engine/Interpreter/environment.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/environment.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/expression.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/expression.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/interpreter.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/interpreter.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/interpretersystem.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/interpretersystem.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/lexer.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/lexer.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/parser.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/parser.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/pginterpreter.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/pginterpreter.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/prettyprinter.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/resolver.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/resolver.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/scriptcallable.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/statement.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/statement.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/systemfunction.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/systemfunction.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/token.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/token.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/valuable.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/valuable.h

        src/Engine/Loaders/fontloader.cpp
        src/Engine/Loaders/fontloader.h
        src/Engine/Loaders/stb_image.h
        src/Engine/Loaders/tileloader.cpp
        src/Engine/Loaders/tileloader.h

        src/Engine/Maths/noise.cpp
        src/Engine/Maths/noise.h
        src/Engine/Maths/pathfinding.h
        src/Engine/Maths/randomnumbergenerator.cpp
        src/Engine/Maths/randomnumbergenerator.h

        src/Engine/Memory/blockingconcurrentqueue.h
        src/Engine/Memory/concurrentqueue.h
        src/Engine/Memory/elementtype.cpp
        src/Engine/Memory/elementtype.h
        src/Engine/Memory/lightweightsemaphore.h
        src/Engine/Memory/memorypool.h
        src/Engine/Memory/parallelfor.cpp
        src/Engine/Memory/parallelfor.h
        src/Engine/Memory/rwlock.h
        src/Engine/Memory/threadpool.h

        src/Engine/Renderer/mesh.cpp
        src/Engine/Renderer/mesh.h
        src/Engine/Renderer/particle.cpp
        src/Engine/Renderer/particle.h
        src/Engine/Renderer/renderer.cpp
        src/Engine/Renderer/renderer.h
        src/Engine/Renderer/renderermodule.h

        src/Engine/Scene/sceneloader.cpp
        src/Engine/Scene/sceneloader.h
        src/Engine/Scene/scenemanager.cpp
        src/Engine/Scene/scenemanager.h

        src/Engine/Shader/shader.cpp
        src/Engine/Shader/shader.h

        src/Engine/Systems/coremodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/coresystems.h
        src/Engine/Systems/logmodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/scenemodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/sentencemodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/shape2Dmodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/texture2Dmodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/timemodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/uimodule.cpp
        src/Engine/Systems/uimodule.h

        src/Engine/UI/button.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/button.h
        src/Engine/UI/focusable.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/focusable.h
        src/Engine/UI/listview.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/listview.h
        src/Engine/UI/scrollable.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/scrollable.h
        src/Engine/UI/sentencesystem.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/sentencesystem.h
        src/Engine/UI/textinput.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/textinput.h
        src/Engine/UI/uianimation.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/uianimation.h
        src/Engine/UI/uiconstant.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/uiconstant.h
        src/Engine/UI/uisystem.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/uisystem.h
)

target_include_directories(PgEngine PRIVATE src/Engine)
target_include_directories(PgEngine PRIVATE src/GameElements)

if(TARGET SDL2::SDL2main)
    target_link_libraries(PgEngine PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2main)
endif()

# Todo fix ttf doens't work

# target_link_libraries(PgEngine PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2-static SDL2_ttf::SDL2_ttf-static SDL2_mixer::SDL2_mixer-static glm)
target_link_options(PgEngine PRIVATE -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Emscripten")
    set_target_properties(PgEngine
        PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".html"
        LINK_FLAGS " -s USE_FREETYPE=1 -sGL_ENABLE_GET_PROC_ADDRESS -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 -s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1 -s SAFE_HEAP=1 --bind -s WASM=1 -O3 -s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=0 -s GL_UNSAFE_OPTS=0 -s ASSERTIONS=1 -s GL_ASSERTIONS=1 -s INVOKE_RUN=0 -std=c++17 -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s FULL_ES3=1 -s USE_GLFW=3 -s OFFSCREENCANVAS_SUPPORT=1")

        #--bind -m32 -s USE_FREETYPE=1 -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s WASM=0 -s MIN_WEBGL_VERSION=1 -s ABORT_ON_WASM_EXCEPTIONS=1 -g2 -s USE_GLFW=3 -sSAFE_HEAP")
    
    target_link_libraries(PgEngine PRIVATE SDL2_mixer::SDL2_mixer-static glm)
else()
    target_link_libraries(PgEngine PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2-static SDL2_mixer::SDL2_mixer-static glm libglew_static)
endif()

#target_link_libraries(PgEngine SDL2main SDL2-static SDL2_mixer-static SDL2_ttf-static glm)

target_sources(TetrisClone PRIVATE
        src/Engine/configuration.h
        src/Engine/configuration.cpp
        src/Engine/constant.h
        src/Engine/gl_debug.hpp
        src/Engine/logger.h
        src/Engine/logger.cpp
        src/Engine/serialization.cpp
        src/Engine/serialization.h
        src/Engine/window.cpp
        src/Engine/window.h

        src/Engine/2D/simple2dobject.cpp
        src/Engine/2D/simple2dobject.h
        src/Engine/2D/texture.cpp
        src/Engine/2D/texture.h

        src/Engine/Audio/audiomodule.h
        src/Engine/Audio/audiosystem.cpp
        src/Engine/Audio/audiosystem.h

        src/Engine/ECS/callable.h
        src/Engine/ECS/commanddispatcher.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/commanddispatcher.h
        src/Engine/ECS/componentregistry.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/componentregistry.h
        src/Engine/ECS/ecsmodule.h
        src/Engine/ECS/entity.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/entity.h
        src/Engine/ECS/entitycreationsystem.h
        src/Engine/ECS/entitysystem.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/entitysystem.h
        src/Engine/ECS/eventlistener.h
        src/Engine/ECS/group.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/group.h
        src/Engine/ECS/identifiers.h
        src/Engine/ECS/loggersystem.h
        src/Engine/ECS/sparseset.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/sparseset.h
        src/Engine/ECS/system.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/system.h
        src/Engine/ECS/uniqueid.cpp
        src/Engine/ECS/uniqueid.h

        src/Engine/Event/eventloop.cpp
        src/Engine/Event/eventloop.h

        src/Engine/Files/filemanager.cpp
        src/Engine/Files/filemanager.h
        src/Engine/Files/fileparser.cpp
        src/Engine/Files/fileparser.h

        src/Engine/Helpers/date.h
        src/Engine/Helpers/detector.h
        src/Engine/Helpers/openglobject.cpp
        src/Engine/Helpers/openglobject.h

        src/Engine/Input/input.cpp
        src/Engine/Input/input.h
        src/Engine/Input/inputcomponent.cpp
        src/Engine/Input/inputcomponent.h
        src/Engine/Input/inputmodule.h

        src/Engine/Interpreter/environment.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/environment.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/expression.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/expression.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/interpreter.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/interpreter.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/interpretersystem.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/interpretersystem.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/lexer.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/lexer.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/parser.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/parser.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/pginterpreter.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/pginterpreter.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/prettyprinter.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/resolver.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/resolver.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/scriptcallable.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/statement.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/statement.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/systemfunction.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/systemfunction.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/token.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/token.h
        src/Engine/Interpreter/valuable.cpp
        src/Engine/Interpreter/valuable.h

        src/Engine/Loaders/fontloader.cpp
        src/Engine/Loaders/fontloader.h
        src/Engine/Loaders/stb_image.h
        src/Engine/Loaders/tileloader.cpp
        src/Engine/Loaders/tileloader.h

        src/Engine/Maths/noise.cpp
        src/Engine/Maths/noise.h
        src/Engine/Maths/pathfinding.h
        src/Engine/Maths/randomnumbergenerator.cpp
        src/Engine/Maths/randomnumbergenerator.h

        src/Engine/Memory/blockingconcurrentqueue.h
        src/Engine/Memory/concurrentqueue.h
        src/Engine/Memory/elementtype.cpp
        src/Engine/Memory/elementtype.h
        src/Engine/Memory/lightweightsemaphore.h
        src/Engine/Memory/memorypool.h
        src/Engine/Memory/parallelfor.cpp
        src/Engine/Memory/parallelfor.h
        src/Engine/Memory/rwlock.h
        src/Engine/Memory/threadpool.h

        src/Engine/Renderer/mesh.cpp
        src/Engine/Renderer/mesh.h
        src/Engine/Renderer/particle.cpp
        src/Engine/Renderer/particle.h
        src/Engine/Renderer/renderer.cpp
        src/Engine/Renderer/renderer.h
        src/Engine/Renderer/renderermodule.h

        src/Engine/Scene/sceneloader.cpp
        src/Engine/Scene/sceneloader.h
        src/Engine/Scene/scenemanager.cpp
        src/Engine/Scene/scenemanager.h

        src/Engine/Shader/shader.cpp
        src/Engine/Shader/shader.h

        src/Engine/Systems/coremodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/coresystems.h
        src/Engine/Systems/logmodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/scenemodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/sentencemodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/shape2Dmodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/texture2Dmodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/timemodule.h
        src/Engine/Systems/uimodule.cpp
        src/Engine/Systems/uimodule.h

        src/Engine/UI/button.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/button.h
        src/Engine/UI/focusable.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/focusable.h
        src/Engine/UI/listview.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/listview.h
        src/Engine/UI/scrollable.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/scrollable.h
        src/Engine/UI/sentencesystem.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/sentencesystem.h
        src/Engine/UI/textinput.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/textinput.h
        src/Engine/UI/uianimation.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/uianimation.h
        src/Engine/UI/uiconstant.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/uiconstant.h
        src/Engine/UI/uisystem.cpp
        src/Engine/UI/uisystem.h

        src/GameElements/Systems/basicsystems.h

        src/Tetris/app.h
        src/Tetris/app.cpp
        src/Tetris/tetromino.h
        src/Tetris/tetromino.cpp
)

target_include_directories(TetrisClone PRIVATE src/Engine)
target_include_directories(TetrisClone PRIVATE src/GameElements)
target_include_directories(TetrisClone PRIVATE src/Tetris)

if(TARGET SDL2::SDL2main)
    target_link_libraries(TetrisClone PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2main)
endif()

# Todo fix ttf doens't work

# target_link_libraries(PgEngine PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2-static SDL2_ttf::SDL2_ttf-static SDL2_mixer::SDL2_mixer-static glm)
target_link_options(TetrisClone PRIVATE -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Emscripten")
    set_target_properties(TetrisClone
        PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".html"
        LINK_FLAGS " -s USE_FREETYPE=1 -sGL_ENABLE_GET_PROC_ADDRESS -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 -s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1 -s SAFE_HEAP=1 --bind -s WASM=1 -O3 -s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=0 -s GL_UNSAFE_OPTS=0 -s ASSERTIONS=1 -s GL_ASSERTIONS=1 -s INVOKE_RUN=0 -std=c++17 -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s FULL_ES3=1 -s USE_GLFW=3 -s OFFSCREENCANVAS_SUPPORT=1")

        #--bind -m32 -s USE_FREETYPE=1 -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s WASM=0 -s MIN_WEBGL_VERSION=1 -s ABORT_ON_WASM_EXCEPTIONS=1 -g2 -s USE_GLFW=3 -sSAFE_HEAP")
    
    target_link_libraries(TetrisClone PRIVATE SDL2_mixer::SDL2_mixer-static glm)
else()
    target_link_libraries(TetrisClone PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2-static SDL2_mixer::SDL2_mixer-static glm libglew_static)
endif()
```

Here are the version of my modules:
emcc -v
emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement + linker emulating GNU ld) 3.1.51 (c0c2ca1314672a25699846b4663701bcb6f69cca)
clang version 18.0.0git (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project f2464ca317bfeeedddb7cbdea3c2c8ec487890bb)
Target: wasm32-unknown-emscripten
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: Z:\Emscripten\emsdk\upstream\bin

and

cmake.exe --version
cmake version 3.26.4

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).